# What is the best option for my JIRA integration?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I want to write JIRA integration to implement my own nodejs backend, but I’m confused by the options. I just want to send issues and similar events to my own backend regardless of user input. So I want to proceed as an application. I also don’t want to develop modules on separate pages or jira. I just want to send the data to my own backend without user oauth. As far as I understand this doesn’t fit forge.

How can I proceed, can you help?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think easiest option is to define Jira webhook:
https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/manage-webhooks/
It can call you nodejs backend.

Other option is to create Connect plugin:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/getting-started-with-connect/

Also you could use Jira Automation with `Send web request` component:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/Automation-for-Jira-Send-web-request-using-Jira-REST-API/ba-p/1443828